# Is there any way to store data like the way of matlab in c program？

Tags: c, matlab

I've got 32 different copies of point cloud coordinate data in .txt form. Each of them has nearly 5000000 lines.

Every time when I want to use them to get some specific information. I need to use the fgets function to read all of them in C language. It takes too much time. Is there any way to store the information on disk in a way that it can be read faster?

[image]

In MATLAB I can store them in a MAT-file, which can be read very quickly.  But in MATLAB the speed of calculation is so slow and now I'm going to transplant the program to C language.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: If you stored your data in a file such that you could calculate *where* in the file the data you want is, you could "jump" to it without having to read everything in between.

Comment: You can store the numbers in binary format instead of text format, which will be much, much faster to load. For example a single call of `fwrite` can write a whole array of numbers to disk, which you can read in again with `fread`.

Comment: You are processing one more line of the file than exists. Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) Use the return value from `fgets()` to control the loop: `while(fgets(...) != NULL)`

Comment: It's unclear what form exactly "point cloud coordinate data" takes, but yes, it is possible to store a whole data set in memory instead of reading it from and writing it to a file every time.  5,000,000 lines sounds like a medium-sized data set.  You should have no problem keeping one such set in memory unless you are on an *extremely* memory-constrained system.  You might even be able to keep all 32 in memory at once, but depending on the details of the data and the computer, that could be too much.

Comment: The suggestion from @CrisLuengo also means you can seek directly to a particular record, which you can't do with a text file.

Comment: I accepted the suggestion from @CrisLuengo. It's much faster to read when I transform the txt-format to bin-format. It's easy and effective. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that your file contents are something like

> coordinate example
> 1255,-2723

What you could do is use sscanf to store it in a C variable

```
while(!feof(fp)) {
    fgets(buff, 1000, fp);
    sscanf(buff,"%i,%i\n", &var1, &var2); 
}
```

where `var1` and `var2` could be arrays as large as the largest valid line number count for your input file. And you could have them indexed by your while loop

```
int var1[MAX];
int var2[MAX];

int i=0; 

while(!feof(fp)) {
    fgets(buff, 1000, fp);
    sscanf(buff,"%i,%i\n", var1+i, var2+i); 
    i++;
}
```

That way you could read the file only once and keep the data cached and reference it by line number, Ideally you would want to dynamically allocate the memory for this with either `malloc` or `new`

Comment: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) This code would process the last line of the file twice. Also there is no need to put `\n` in the `sscanf` format string: in fact you should not do so.

Comment: It's also unclear how this answers the question, which was how to avoid reading the text file every time some data is needed from it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).